# Hello! I need help wich datetime

Tags: python-3.x, timedelta

I wrote this code:

```
chegada = input('Enter arrival time: "Hours: Minutes" ')
saida = input('Inform the time of departure: "Hours: Minutes" ')

fmt = '%H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(saida, fmt) - datetime.strptime(chegada, fmt)
if tdelta.days < 0:
    tdelta = timedelta(days=0, seconds=tdelta.seconds,
        microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
```

Now i wanted to know how to convert in seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

chegada = input('Enter arrival time: "Hours: Minutes" ')
saida = input('Inform the time of departure: "Hours: Minutes" ')

fmt = '%H:%M'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(saida, fmt) - datetime.strptime(chegada, fmt)
if tdelta.days < 0:
    tdelta = timedelta(days=0, seconds=tdelta.seconds,
        microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
print(tdelta)
print(tdelta.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Oh, very good! thanks thanks

Comment: glad to help...